# Using Moq to Mock KeyVaultClient for Unit Test C#

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, nunit

I am trying to mock the KeyVaultClient using mock so that my unit test won't depend on my Azure KeyVault service when I run the test. Is there any code similar to what I used to mock the SecretClient?

```
// Create a page of enumeration results
Page<SecretProperties> secretResponsePage = Page<SecretProperties>.FromValues(
    new[] {
              new SecretProperties("secret1"),
              new SecretProperties("secret2"),
              new SecretProperties("secret3"),
            },
            continuationToken: null,
            Mock.Of<Response>());

// Create a pageable that consists of a single page
AsyncPageable<SecretProperties> pageable = AsyncPageable<SecretProperties>.FromPages(new[] { secretResponsePage });

// Setup a client mock object to return the pageable when GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync is called
var clientMock = new Mock<SecretClient>();
     clientMock.Setup(c => c.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .Returns(pageable);
```

Comment: Moq can only mock methods that are marked as `virtual` or interfaces. I suggest wrapping `SecretClient` in your own class, and create your own interface from it.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static KeyVaultService _clientService;
    private static Mock<IConfiguration> _mockConfig;

    public KeyVaultServiceTest()
    {
        _mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();            
        _clientService = new KeyVaultService(configuration);
    }    


    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetSecretKeyVault_UnitTest()
    {
        string secret = "This is sceret key";

        Mock<SecretBundle> mockSecret = new Mock<SecretBundle>();
        mockSecret.SetupGet(x => x.Value).Returns("secret");

        Mock<KeyVaultClient> clientMock = new Mock<KeyVaultClient>();
        clientMock.Setup(x => x.GetSecretAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(mockSecret.Object));

        _clientService.SetServiceClient(clientMock.Object);
        _clientService.GetSecretKeyVault("test");   
    }
```

Comment: Please don't just post code without explaining what it does and how.